# Microsoft Graph API status code 404 not found error

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, outlook-restapi

I am new to Azure and Microsoft Graph API.
I am trying to access: `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages`
and I am getting a `404 Not Found.

I took the access token and decrypted in JWT and I can see the access token contains my name and credentials and the scopes defined are :

`Directory.AccessAsUser.All` `Directory.Read.All` `email` `Files.ReadWrite` `Group.Read.All` `Mail.Send` `offline_access` `openid` `profil.Read`

Can someone please suggest why I am getting a bad request?

Comment: Does the token also contain `"aud": "https://graph.microsoft.com"`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to `list` (read) the mail messages (as described [here](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/user_list_messages)) you need the `Mail.Read` or `Mail.ReadWrite` (if you also want to write messages) permission (scope).

With respect to mailing functionality you only have requested (or granted?) `Mail.Send` permission which only allows you `send` message (as described [here](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/message_send)).

The `email` claim is OpenID Connect specific claim and provides the logged-in user's email as claim. It has nothing to do with Exchange Online and sending/receiving e-mails.

Comment: Thank you. Well I was just curious about "Access directory as the signed in user" permission. Is it the mandatory permission ? because groups and some other permissions didn't showed up until i added this permission .

Comment: The **only** scope you require to list mail messages (`/messages`) is `Mail.Read`. In general, you'll also want `User.Read` so you can read the current user's profile (`/me`). The rest are related to other endpoints or OpenID.